# Scrollbar does not show-up

Tags: qml, scrollbar

This ScrollBar does not show up, and I don't understand why.
At the best of my attemps, I got a big red rectangle, but no way to use it to scroll the idRootsGrid horizontally. What I'm missing ?

```
Flickable {
    id: flickable
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.preferredHeight: idRootsGrid.implicitHeight
    clip: true
    ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar {
        //anchors.top: flickable.top
        anchors.bottom: flickable.bottom
        //anchors.right: flickable.right
        //anchors.left: flickable.left
        active: true
        visible: true
        contentItem: Rectangle {
            id: contentItem_rect2
            radius: implicitHeight / 2
            color: "Red"
            width: 10 // This will be overridden by the width of the scrollbar
            height: 10 // This will be overridden based on the size of the scrollbar
        }
        //size: 10
        width: 5
   //height: 10
    }
    GridLayout {
        id: idRootsGrid
        columnSpacing: 5
        rowSpacing: 10
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        rows: 1
        ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two problems in your code. The main problem is that your Scrollbar's contentItem needs to have an `implicitHeight` defined. It uses `implicitHeight` rather than `height` to determine how to draw it.

And second, your Flickable needs to know how big its contents are, so I had to set its `contentWidth` property to the size of your GridLayout.

```
Flickable {
    id: flickable
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.preferredHeight: idRootsGrid.implicitHeight
    clip: true

    contentWidth: idRootsGrid.width

    ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar {
        anchors.bottom: flickable.bottom
        active: true
        visible: true

        contentItem: Rectangle {
            id: contentItem_rect2
            radius: implicitHeight / 2
            color: "Red"

            implicitHeight: 10
        }
    }
    GridLayout { ... }
}
```